# Does Spring Cloud Contract support serial dependencies between microservices?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Let's say that we have 3 Microservices A, B and C. We want to test a functionality of microservice A, which depends on microservice B. However, the response of microservice B also depends on the microservice C. Does Spring Cloud Contract support such cases? Because by reading the documentation I get that when a contract is created for the interaction between A-B (and inserted in B), the automatically generated test in B will fail since it waits a response from C in order to provide an answer. And even if we have another contract for the interaction B-C, this means that we have to modify the auto-generated test in B, so that the test is successful. Is there a way when creating a contract for A-B to specify that this also depends on the interaction B-C?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are reading more into the documentation than is actually there. The contract is not asserted when you test the consumer, it just generates stub responses that match the contract. So, in your scenario, to test service A you only need stubs from service B. You don't really even need the contracts, and you don't need anything from service C. I wonder if you actually tried it and something didn't work?

Comment: Dave is right. What you have to do is to create 2 separate contracts. For service B and for service C. That way you can create 2 sets of stubs - for service B and for service C. Then you can check integrations between A with B, and B with C. Remember that contract testing in principle is NOT about testing the functionality. It's about checking the API correctness.